# How could forces without metal or plastic face up to conventional forces?

Tags: science-fiction, warfare

The basic concept here is that armies in this setting use powerful shield generators (carried in armoured vehicles) to create shields that inorganic matter cannot pass through - no metals, no plastics. These shields form a hemisphere over the entire army, protecting them from outside fire. Therefore, armies need to send in skirmishers without any metal or plastic to disable the shield generators, if they want to bring their artillery/airpower/etc to bear on the enemy.

What armour and weapons could these skirmishers use?

Medium sci-fi - no space magic, at least some adherence to science, but willing to bend the rules to a significant extend in favour of 'rule of cool'.

EDIT: For those asking about the nature of the shield, the basic concept is that it’s essentially a dense solid when touching inorganic matter, and so will push such things away from it as it moves. I’m open to the concept of it being stationary while active. So a person with a metal filling would essentially have their filling pushed with whatever force they’re meeting the field with, potentially ripping it from their tooth and through the back of their head. A bomb encased in wood wouldn’t penetrate.

Comment: Plastics are organic chemistry, it's made of the same stuff humans are. (Primarily, Carbon, Hydrogen, and Oxygen)... So depending on how the shield actually functions, it shouldn't let people (humans) through either.

Comment: More information needed.  How thick is the shield?  It's a hemisphere - how does it interact with uneven ground around it?  How far does the shielded surface extend from the generator?  How does metallic and/or inorganic matter completely encased in organic matter interact with the shield?  (Humans with metal fillings in their teeth?  250 lb bomb encased in a tree trunk?  Iron in red blood cells?)  Does light pass through the shield, or are both sides effectively blind?  Depending on answers, weapon may be near-perfect defence, especially in absence of breathable atmosphere?

Comment: Need a bit more info on what happens on contact with shield. Does it just bounce off? Does it get blocked by barricades? How big is the shield? I think most bombs would probably work at killing people. Land mines or any attack coming from underneath the shield as well should work

Comment: How about napalm?

Comment: Can they just fly over it and drop (non metal/plastic containing) bombs?

Comment: Define "organic" and "non-organic". There is iron in blood. Does that mean that any person that walks though the shield falls dead on the other side from near instant asphyxiation, while leaving behind big humanoid-shaped smudge of greenish dust on the shield where the Fe2+ ions have deposited, along with the oxygen it was carrying?  
  
Point being: nature cares not for human-made labels such as "organic" and "non-organic", we made them up, rather arbitrarilly. For example: gasoline is an [organic compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_compound), while enamel in your teeth is not.

Comment: Can you clarify what does pass through the shield?  When it comes to warfare, you can be 100% certain that both sides will abuse the laws of physics to the utmost in order to get an edge.  For a believable setting, you will want to pick the most effective thing that can possibly go through the shield, and then assume that the forces will use that.  Also, the first thing I will do is dig a tunnel under the shield.  If I can't do that, that says a great deal about how the shield works - because it's going to have to go throguh a ton of inorganic matter underground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ceramics are non-organic, but neither metal nor "plastic".

Material Science knows 3 material classes of non-biological origin: Metals, Polymers, and [Ceramics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic). It's possible to create many modern weapons from ceramics if you allow them to be bulkier in some areas to mitigate the inherent stresses of ceramics. Some ceramics are even superior to metals: Tungsten carbide is a ceramic and one of the best penetrators. Gun barrels would be thicker, even if made from exotic Metal Like Ceramics.

However, almost all ceramics are inorganic in chemistry terms and thus "non-organic".

### Most Polymers are organic, not inorganic.

[The definition of organic in chemistry is "Contains Carbon atoms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_chemistry). Everything else is defined as [inorganic chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inorganic_chemistry).

Almost all Plastics are organic compounds, safe for silicones, which use silicon instead of carbon and are classed in inorganic chemistry. As such, your limitation is paradoxical in itself: the shield generators either block plastics and thus **all** organic compounds (including humans and wood), or they don't.

Polymer weapons can be easily created: most explosives are compounds from organic chemistry (not black powder though). To blow up a building using bricks of C4 ([RDX is organic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDX)) together with an initiator of [Mercury-II-Fulminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury(II)_fulminate) (also organic) in a polymer tube would pass through the shield, if not blocking organic is read strictly.

### Time

Even ignoring the problem if the shields block organic or ceramic substances or not, the shields block Oxygen. Oxygen is an inorganic compound, it is clearly on the list of blocked compounds ("*shields that inorganic matter cannot pass through*"), and thus the only thing the attackers need to do is wait: At some point the inside of the shield will be lethal just from the people inside breathing, unless the shield is large enough to contain about one tree per ten people to create oxygen.

### Biological Warfare

Usually, it is sufficient to kill anyone inside to win. [Biological Warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_warfare) relies on bacteria, viruses, and other [Biological Agents.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_agent) Those would easily pass the shield no matter how you define "non organic", and can be deployed by smashing containers of the agents against the shield.

### Chemical Warfare

Many [Chemical Weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_weapon) are ogranic compounds, such as [organophosphates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organophosphate) ([Rainbow Herbicides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Herbicides)). [Mustard gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_gas) is also organic. Those would penetrate the shield and can be deployed the same way as the biological agents by smacking the canisters against the shield.

### Radiation is light!

Radiation based weaponry, such as Lasers or gamma radiation is not explicitly listed as allowed or not, as it is technically light and thus neither allowed nor disallowed. If allowed to pass, this opens two ways: One could confront the contents of the shield with infrared lasers and cook anyone inside. Or one blasts the contents with harsh ionizing electromagnetic radiation, a.k.a. gamma radiation. Then the people inside will soon suffer from radiation sickness and the materials on the surface will become sources of radiation themselves.

Disallowing Radiation means, that the shield would be fully black and anyone inside would be unable to look out in any way.

### Neutron Weapons are neither organic nor inorganic but use subatomic particles.

Neutrons are subatomic particles and [can be weaponized.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_bomb) A harsh blast of neutron radiation, such as from a nuke, would irradiate anything in the vicinity, and turn it into irradiated material. It's unlikely the shield blocks them, unless the shield blocks every form of matter.

Answer (score 4):

Organic poisons and toxins, on organic support is the way to go. Just to give you a couple examples:

- [Curare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curare) poisoned darts: killing targets since prehistory, 100% organic.
- [Sharpened bamboo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punji_stick), spread with rotting corpses, poison or feces. The nightmare of US forces during the Vietnam war.

In pure guerrilla style, a few skirmishers will intrude the shield, disable it by taking out its operators and then have the exposed troops being targeted by their comrades.

Answer (score 3):

## Cruise missile

If these plastic/metal blocking shields are common enough that it's worth creating a countermeasure, they could just build one, especially in medium sci-fi. Yes, not being allowed to use ""metal"" or ""plastics"" imposes some severe limitations, there are still plenty of materials you could use like:

- Directly biological material, grown for purpose (big one)
- Glass (!)
- Ceramics
- Silicon (technically not a metal, so you could probably build a metal-free computer)
- "Natural" rubbers
- Fibers and composites (you can probably make ""plastic""-free carbon fiber material)
- Wood, bone, etc
- Minerals, stone, etc
- Chemical materials (solid/liquid rocket propellant, explosives)

Specifically, a cruise missile has four main components:

### Structure

You could build something strong and lightweight out of some plastic-free composite. Maybe a carbon-fiber tube or build it out of extremely tough glass (Borosilicate?). Should be rather doable.

### Avionics

Probably the most difficult part. Since silicon is not a metal, it would work, and you could select semiconductor doping materials that are non-metallic to create transistors. Then, instead of wires, use graphene, carbon nanotubes, or something more exotic like doped diamond to create conductors. I'm pretty sure that you could make the entire guidance and navigation computer without metal or plastic, including components like camera/seeker with today's technology if you *really* wanted to do so. You'd still need to create actuators, but again, ceramics, glasses, and other non-metal materials could be used here to realize control of aero surfaces.

However, if this is impossible, in a medium sci-fi setting it should be rather easy to "vat-grow" your avionics. Instead of servos or an electronic computer, grow artificial muscle and brain in a lab. Then, train the brain to do the flight guidance tasks and presto. Today, we can already manufacture "brains on a chip" where we essentially grow brain cells on a petri dish and then train them to perform tasks, so I don't see why something slightly more advanced could be done in the future.

### Propulsion

Just mix together a solid rocket propellant, like an ammonium perchlorate composite (APCP). This is a modern formula, and does not require metals nor is it really what you'd consider a "plastic". Formulate it for long burn times, so that it spreads thrust out over a long period of time and maybe add a discarded high-thrust booster stage.

### Payload

Mix together an explosive like TNT that doesn't contain metal nor is considered a plastic, and you're golden.

---

### Summary

In summary, while it would be a bit of engineering effort and the product would probably perform worse in all metrics compared to what could be made if metals/plastics are allowed, there is no fundamental reason why we couldn't build a no-metal, no-plastic cruise missile today.

A "medium sci-fi" setting should have no problem with this.

If you still want to make it more difficult to take out these shields, maybe you could have these "shield penetrating missiles" be extremely expensive or something.

Also, is there a reason why they can't just bomb the shield generator from high altitude (or even orbit) with a non-metal, non-plastic bomb? Same construction guidelines apply.

---

*Editorial*: Your line "armies need to send in skirmishers without any metal or plastic to disable the shield generators" and the general vibe seems like you're trying to make melee combat work in sci-fi, and thus working backwards. It may make more sense if you just asked "how do I get primitive melee combat in my sci-fi story" or looked at one of the existing questions on this topic rather than nailing down a specific solution from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

- [Tactical nuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_nuclear_weapon)
- [Trees](https://youtu.be/nLbE8g1b4zc?si=Kp40XVOmYV1QGNcr&t=180)
- Flooding

[image]

- [Explosives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-4_(explosive))
- [Sonic weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon)
- [Directed-energy weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed-energy_weapon)
- [Focused sunlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_gun)
- Rocks (catapult, trebuchet, low velocity howitzer... the slow knife, after all...)
- Etc.

On top of that...

- Attack their supply lines. An armored vehicle without fuel is a doorstop.
- Scramble their communications.
- Overwhelm the shield (no shield is perfect). E.G. an avalanche or simply running car after car into it.
- Dig trenches the vehicles can't pass over or through.
- Be more mobile than the shield trucks:

> There is only one tactical principle which is not subject to change. It is to use the means at hand to inflict the maximum amount of wound, death, and destruction on the enemy in the minimum amount of time. Fixed fortifications are a monument to the stupidity of man. (George S. Patton)

Mobile fortifications are simply another form of "fixed fortification." So long as the attacker is faster and more agile (e.g., able to attack behind the lines), the shield trucks might as well be standing still.